# How to make an interface class out of ApplicationDbContext?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

#### I am trying to make an interface out of ApplicationDbContext which extends IdentityDbContext.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, 
                                     IApplicationDbContext
 {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("AppContext")
    {

    }
   // Should I add below line? without any unwanted behavior?
   // public DbSet<ApplicationUser> User { get; set;}
    public  DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
 }
```

#### My interface will be

```
 public interface IApplicationDbContext : IDisposable
 {
     // Should I add below line?
     // DbSet<ApplicationUser> User { get;}
     DbSet<Book> Books { get; }
     int SaveChanges();
 }
```

#### On problem with this approach is that I loose access to 'Users' that came from IdentityDbContext.Users

```
 private ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();

 ctx.Users.somthing() works
```

#### but with below, compiler complains

```
 private IApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbCOntext();

 ctx.Users.something..
```

#### IApplicationDbContext does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extensions method 'Users'...

I think I am missing a crucial concept here.

would you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delcare `ctx` as an instance of `IApplicationDbContext` you're delcaring your intent that you only wish to know about those things in the `IApplicationDbContext` interface, regardless of what the concrete implementation of the interface happens to be.

If you want access to both `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` members *and* `IApplicationDbContext` members, you need to delcare a type which is both of those things, e.g. your `ApplicationDbContext` class.

Alternatively, and preferably, rather than extend `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` in your concrete implementation of `ApplicationDbContext`, you could instead follow the principle of prefering composition over inheritance, and allow `ApplicationDbContext` to own an instance of `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, e.g.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> _dbContext;
    public IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get { return _dbContext.Users; } }

    public ApplicationDbContext(IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

and, if you needed to, alter your interface definition to also provide the `Users` property. This allows you to still access the information you need, while hiding the information you don't. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding for more information.

Comment: Check my update - there is no single "correct" way, but based on what you've shown, I'd argue against extending.

Comment: Thank you. Any reason behind having IDbSet<ApplicationUser> instead Dbset<ApplicationUser>?

Comment: I was looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497626(v=vs.108).aspx, and that's the type of the property there, but I'm not sure if that's actually the class you're using or not. More generally, exposing interfaces is preferable to exposing concretions for the same reasons as above - reliance on an abstraction allows flexibility to change without affecting clients of your class. A concrete example is when creating unit tests on classes that take a dependency on `IApplicationDbContext`, it's much easier to create fake/mock implementations if its returns are *also* easily mocked.